# D3 v4 .rangeBand() equivalent

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In D3 version 4.x, `d3.scale.ordinal()` has been changed to `d3.scaleOrdinal` and `d3.rangeRoundBands` has been changed to:

```
d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([range]);
```

To find the width of a band, what is the equivalent of `d3.rangeBand()`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To find the width of the band in a band scale you have to use:

```
scale.bandwidth();
```

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#band_bandwidth), `bandwidth()`:

> Returns the width of each band.

Here is a demo:

```js
var scale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "foobaz"])
  .range([0, 100]);
  
console.log("The width of each band is " + scale.bandwidth() + " pixels")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, the bandwidth depends on the number of elements in the domain, the extent of the range and the paddings. Here is the same snippet above, with paddings:

```js
var scale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "foobaz"])
  .range([0, 100])
  .paddingOuter(0.25)
  
console.log("The width of each band is " + scale.bandwidth() + " pixels")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```